# Interpreting Combinations for Four of a Kind

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

To calculate the number of ways to make a four of a kind in a five card poker hand, one could reason as follows.

- There are 13 values you can select for the four of a kind: ${13 \choose 1}$
- The fifth can be any of the 52 - 4 remaining cards: ${52 - 4 \choose 1}$

So the total number of combinations is simply ${13 \choose 1}{48 \choose 1} = 13 \times 48 = 624$

I've also seen this equivalent calculation, but I'm not sure how to interpret it:

${13 \choose 1}{12 \choose 1}{4 \choose 1} = 624$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically it's the same as yours, except here for the fifth card, you consider the card number and card suit separately.

$
{13 \choose 1}:
$
there are $13$ cards from which to choose the one which will appear $4$ times.

$
{12 \choose 1}: 
$
there are $13-1=12$ remaining choices (up to suit equivalence for the $5$th card)

$
{4 \choose 1}:
$
there are $4$ choices for the suit of the $5$th card.